# Unable to load any JS files in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use `wp_enqueue_script()` function to load my script files + jquery but the files do not show up in my source code...

Here is my code in the functions.php file:

```
function theme_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bxslider' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'general' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/general.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
};
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

Please let me know where I am making the mistake. Thanks.

EDIT > I have also tried the code below, still not working:

```
function theme_js() {
  wp_register_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script( 'bxslider' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_register_script( 'skrollr' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_register_script( 'general' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/general.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
};
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

Comment: Have you registered your scripts first with [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)? Also it's `wp_enqueue_script`, you spelled it wrong.

Comment: thanks, fixed spelling but still no luck... I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after some research:

```
function theme_js() {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', false, '1.10.2', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bxslider' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'general' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/general.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
};
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```